# How can I merge a standard hard drive to a hard drive with the os on it to act as one?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I have an extra drive (Internal) and it has nothing on it including no partitions on it on my windows 7 laptop. Is there a way to make the Disk 2"MBR" Drive (I don't know what MBR means but that's what it is called on my partition tool) and my Disk 1"MBR" that contains my operating system and all my programs on it into one big disk.

All I really am trying to do is make it where I can install everything into one spot instead of having to install new games onto the opposite drive because there isn't enough space on the other. I know a little bit about RAID and if it's possible to RAID my drives to make the computer run better in any way please let me know how.

Also after I did all this would I have to do it again if I factory data reset my pc, or if I put a windows seven boot disk in and re-installed the operating system? I plan on doing so soon so I can give this computer as a gift to my fiance. I want to do this once and don't mind losing data to improve performance or convenience of the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, what you suggest would be possible, but I wouldn't do it, simply due to the fact that this would screw you up once you forget booting without the external drive or in case there's some problem. Also it makes the whole laptop a lot less mobile.

What I'd suggest is using **Symbolic Links** to link both drives or even easier: **Just mount the external drive as a folder** rather than using a drive letter for it.

Just open disk management, right click the partition on your external drive and use the option to assign a drive letter. Just instead of assigning a new letter, pick the option to assign a local path.

Comment: The second drive isn't external it's internal I just never needed it until now and find it might be easier this way. I apologize for not being very clear, I didn't know exactly how to say it.

Comment: @SebastianU. Ah ok. :) But even then, both my ideas are still valid and should offer you the easiest and most convenient way to link both drives, while still keeping their independence.

Comment: Okay I am kind of new to software, how do I create a symbolic link?I apologize if that is asking to much. I tried going to diskmgmt.msc and changing the path of A to link with C the drive partition with my operating system with the most amount of space the okay button was just grayed out.

Comment: @SebastianU. You've been on the right track. Which path did you try? You can't mount it to the root of the file system. You'll have to pick some folder (like `C:\Stuff`).

Comment: Ah okay, I figured out how to do so but it basically created a shortcut to that drive I just want the space to meld, like instead of having to specifically find that folder each time when I install something which is what I am already doing I want to just hit install it automatically goes to C and all I have to do is hit next instead of create a new folder for what I want in my A drive and then look for that folder in my a drive so it doesn't leave a bunch of documents all over and organize like the C drive does. I don't know if that makes complete sense though sorry >.<

Comment: If the second harddrive contain NTFS volumes then you can also mount those in a folder rather than via a drive letter.